# What are the valid DNX --watch flag values?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dnx

I'm working on my first ASP.NET 5 application.  When trying to start the application from the command line by running:

```
dnx web --watch
```

I get the following output:

```
System.FormatException: Value for switch '--watch' is missing.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine.CommandLineConfigurationProvider.Load()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Add(IConfigurationProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.WebApplication.Run(Type startupType, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Program.Main(String[] args)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute(Assembly assembly, String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<ExecuteMain>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

What are the valid values for the `--watch` flag?  I tried giving it a dummy value of 0 then changed some of my controller code, but the change was not reflected.

**Update**

To install `dnx-watch` run the following:

```
dnu commands install Microsoft.Dnx.Watcher
```

Then run your application by doing something like:

```
dnx-watch web
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguments passed after the command name ("web" in your case) are arguments passed to that command. If you want arguments passed to DNX, pass them before: `dnx --watch web`

But, `--watch` will go away. Use `dnx-watch` instead: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/74

Comment: Thanks!  I had just stumbled upon your GitHub issue (https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/2700) and got it working.